# Reading the activeDocument in Photoshop and send it to web page or clipboard API

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm new to Photoshop scripting and javascript. How can I read via code the image inside the active window in Photoshop CS5-C6 and paste that image into a web page DIV?

FYI I'm a complete newbie to programming. My goal is to build a simple Mac App prototype with a wrapper running a web app inside. That web app needs to connect to Photoshop via TCP and read the image inside the selected window document and then paste it somehow into the web app's html. (Photoshop has feature inside the edit menu called 'remote connections' that converts Photoshop into a server and allows any external applications to read/write stuff inside Photoshop by sending javascript over TCP)

So, how can I:

1) Access Photoshop over TCP via javascript?
2) How can I get the image inside the active Photoshop window and paste into the web app?

Comment: @KatieK To access Photoshop I've been trying to use these sample scripts [link](https://gist.github.com/tbuchok) but since I'm new a newbie, I'm not sure what should be tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

I might need some additional information to help more accurately, but if I understand correctly I'd say you are running your code on your local machine.

Please post the development environment you are using (Visual Studio, eclipse, etc.)

**First Approach**
You will want to save you Photoshop image and add that file to your project. Just in case, I would recommend actually moving the image into your project folder first.

So, if you saved the image to "C:/Username/Pictures" - move it to "C:/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MyWebPage"

Once you've done that, just add an IMG tag and the file path. If you moved the image into the project folder, the path should just be the filename:

```
<div>
    <img src="myPhotoshopImage.gif" alt="Image">
</div>
```

You can put whatever you like inside the *alt* quotations (""), it doesn't effect the way it works. You can also specify the dimensions by adding *height* and *width* (this is optional) like so:

```
<div>
    <img src="myPhotoshopImage.gif" alt="Image" height="260" width="420">
</div>
```

**Second Approach**
If you don't want to worry about managing your image files in your project, you can choose to host them online.

First, save your imagine in photoshop. Then choose an image hosting service. I would suggest [ImageShack](http://imageshack.us) for an easy start. I would also suggest creating an account to keep track of everything.

Log in to ImageShack and go to the "Media Upload" tab. Click the "Browse" button and locate your image. Click OK. If you want your image to appear the same as it looks on your computer, make sure "Do Not Resize" is selected. Finally, click "Upload Now" & "Continue to Image Links" on the following page.

You will notice they have generated an HTML link for you already, which will work - but will also act as a link to ImageShack if clicked on. If you want to avoid that, just follow the same pattern:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/2232/123vm.jpg" alt="Image" height="260" width="420">
</div>
```

You'll need to do some research on any other actions you want the embedded image to take. A great place to start is [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com).

**Edit** - Forgot to mention... If you are wanting to use some javascript functions to work with the image, give your image an "id" attribute:

```
<img src="something.jpg" alt="whatever" id="headerImage">
```

You can now access the image via javascript:

```
function foo() {
     var myImage = document.getElementById("headerImage");
     myImage.height = 1000;
     myImage.width = 832;
};
```

Also, if you are having any trouble, make sure your image is saved as a common filetype (not .psd)

Comment: I am using SublimeText2 and Coda 2. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to access Photoshop via TCP from a local web document by using javascript or Adobe's jsx.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python wrapper for connecting to photoshop called [photoshopConnection](https://github.com/theiviaxx/photoshopConnection)

One thing you can do is get the actual file info from PS and then copy the file itself into the webapp. I do not think the photoshop server supports streaming data in the fashion you are looking to.